# prediction accuracy of naive bayes error

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes

I am trying to find the accuracy of the prediction of naive bayes algorithm. It gave me this error

```
Error in table(test[, 1], fit1) : all arguments must have the same length
```

here is my code:

```
nbbayes=naiveBayes(train[,-1],train[,1],data=train)
newdata=test[,-1]
newdata
fit1=predict(nbbayes,newdata)
fit1
tab1=table(test[,1],fit1)
accuracy_nb=sum(diag(tab1))/(sum(tab1))
```

Comment: Can you please make your example reproducible so that we can copy/paste the code and data into our R session and work from there?